# repeating background-image until exact width

Tags: html, css

how can I repeat a background image until exact width?
for example I have a `width: 10px` image and my div is `width: 100px`
now I want my image to repeat-x for 50px and then nothing!
is it possible with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to nest another `div` or `span` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aj7y4/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div {
    background-color: #808080;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

span {
    background: url("http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/xamin/doc/img/delete.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #808080;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. I was already using this solution but I thought there might be a way to do this in CSS

Answer (score 0):

No - You cannot set an image to repeat x times using CSS.

You may want to look at the logic behind what you're trying to accomplish- why not just make the div 50px wide? Or add a centred 50px child div you apply the background image on? Or, make the div 50px wide with either a margin or border of 50px?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the repetition of image with number of times.
Instead of that you can use css tricks.

1. Create div 'A' 100px width
2. Create div 'B' 50px width inside the div 'A'
3. Repeat Background image on Div 'B'.
4. Position Div 'B' where you want the image.

HTML

```
<div class= 'A'>
    <div class='B'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.A {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.B {
    width:50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("link") repeat-x;
}
```